# Implementing Int32.TryParse of FSharp in Haskell

Tags: haskell, f#

I liked the Int32.TryParse function in F# and I wanted to make my own in Haskell:

```
import qualified Control.Exception as CE
handler:: CE.ErrorCall -> IO (Bool,Int)
handler e = return (False,0)
s2Int :: String->Int
s2Int s = read s
tryParse :: String -> IO (Bool,Int)
tryParse s = CE.catch (s2Int s `seq` return (True,read s)) handler
```

Seven lines to parse an Int?! Is there a shorter way?

Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `reads`:

```
tryParse :: String -> (Bool, Int)
tryParse s =
    case reads s of
        [(i, "")] -> (True, i)
        _ -> (False, 0)
```

it would be more idomatic to return a `Maybe Int` instead however:

```
tryParse :: String -> Maybe Int
tryParse s =
    case reads s of
        [(i, "")] -> Just i
        _ -> Nothing
```

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to return `(Bool, Int)`. The only reason it is this way in F# is because it is syntactic sugar over a C# function that takes a mutable `int` and returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read` and get an `Maybe Int` instead:

```
import Text.Read

tryParse :: String -> Maybe Int
tryParse = readMaybe
```

Comment: Way to go, the `TryX` pattern is way too close with `Maybe`.